# I do not know how to install Npgsql version 3.0.3

Tags: microsoft-office, visual-studio, postgresql, powerpivot

I want to install Power Pivot and Power Qwery in Excel for Postgresql. I installed Visual Studio and I installed Npgsql in Visual Studio PM (Package Manager Console). I can see, in Power Qwery properties, "form PostgreSQL" but when I click there and enter the name of the server and user I get an error:

> Details: "PostgreSQL: We were unable to find a database provider with invariant name 'Npgsql'.
>   This error could've been the result of provider-specific client software being required, but missing on this computer.  To download client software for this provider, visit the following site and choose the 64-bit (x64) version of, at minimum, 'Npgsql version 2.0.12': https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=282716"

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this answer:

[Connect to PostgreSQL database from Excel 2013 Power Query with Npgsql](https://superuser.com/questions/950100/connect-to-postgresql-database-from-excel-2013-power-query-with-npgsql)

It worked for Power Qwery but I used Npgsql-2.2.5-net45.zip for Npgsql.dll and Mono.Security.dll files and I used
setup Setup_Npgsql-2.2.5.0-r3-net45.exe 
Setup_Npgsql-2.2.5.0-r2-net45.exe 
Setup_Npgsql-2.2.5.0-net45.exe filles in this combination.
Next I restarted my computer.

Now I can create a connection in Power Query and use this connection to create PowerPivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/install.html):

> The best way to install Npgsql in your project is with [our nuget package, Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/).

Use Nuget. Like for most other .NET stuff.

If you want design-time support in Visual Studio there are instructions given on the install page for that too. It's a bit of a complicated manual setup at the moment.